# BouncyCastle - Create a Store from X509Certificate object

Tags: java, timestamp, bouncycastle, pki

Originally I hoped that the TimestampResponseGenerator would automatically include the public certificate in the response if the request had `setCertReq(true)`, but now my understanding is that I have to manually add them in the [TimestampTokenGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampTokenGenerator.html) using `addCertificates(Store certStore)`. However, I can only seem to get the certificate into a standard Java [certStore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertStore.html), not a BouncyCastle [Store](http://javadox.com/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.53/org/bouncycastle/util/Store.html), and I can't find a way to convert or create the Store object from scratch.

**What is the easiest way to create a BouncyCastle 1.62+ [Store](http://javadox.com/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.53/org/bouncycastle/util/Store.html) object with an X509Certificate object?**

The answer (and bounty) depend on being able to add certificates to the timestamp token in the end. The Store part is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use the `JcaCertStore` class. This can easily be initialized with a certificate collection and then be passed to your `TimestampTokenGenerator` using `addCertificates`.

In this example I did it through a method, since I don't have the exact context you want to place it in, but you can extract the two lines and place them wherever you want of course!

```
public void add(TimeStampTokenGenerator timeStampTokenGenerator, X509Certificate certificate) throws CertificateEncodingException {
    JcaCertStore store = new JcaCertStore(Collections.singleton(certificate));
    timeStampTokenGenerator.addCertificates(store);
}
```

[Javadocs here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/jcajce/JcaCertStore.html)

Comment: Thank you! I need to do a little more investigation to make sure everything is in order, but I think this is it. Hopefully I can release the bounty tomorrow.

Comment: One question in the meantime: The original size of the TimeStampResponse (with a 512 hash) was 2.5KB. Adding the certificate which is 2.1KB, I would expect the resulting size to be ~4.6KB, but I see it it 5.5KB. Is there additional overhead in the Store or the ASN1 structure? (Normally this wouldn't be too big a deal, but I may be storing these so every byte counts). Do these sizes look in par with regular TimeStampResponses you've seen before or does something seem amiss?

Comment: @user8897013 From looking at the source code it might be possible some overhead is created in the `CMSSignedData` class where your certificates are put when the generator is used. (Assuming you're encoding the full response instance). But unless you're storing up in the thousands of these responses it's probably not going to add up to much.

Comment: I was using one million in my case model. That'll be 5.5GB. Reasonable? Thinking on it. Not much different than say 4.5GB without the overhead. Just making sure I'm not making a silly calculation mistake.

Comment: That should be correct. Assuming you'd have a decently sized storage you could probably still store a few million if you really need to